# Sportive (Gran Fondo) Finder

Tags: sport

Is there an app or website where you can enter a climb (e.g. Monte Zoncolan, Alto de L'Angliru) and receive details of a  Sportive (Gran Fondo) which includes it?

Comment: Yes, the route will always tell you about the climbs involved in any sportive...it's how to find that event. Say I have a list of climbs in Europe, and I can take holiday in July, say.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately this sort of reverse search is unlikely to work. It relies on there being some sort of central database of events and their climbs, possibly an international one. While I can find a few fairly complete lists of UK events (in normal years) these lack sufficient information unless the climb is in the name, and you have to look at the individual event information to find out where it goes. Even then, only the most significant climbs tend to be listed, though those are probably what you're looking for.

But there aren't that many events, so the reverse search may not be needed assuming you can find lists at a national level. If you've got a time period of a few weeks, you can probably check all events in mountainous regions in a couple of countries without too much effort - after all you'd only need to do this once per year in spring, and many events run the same route each year. In fact googling the names of the climbs you particularly want to do will get you started.

It would be nice to have such a list, but someone would have to spend quite a bit of time on keeping it up to date.

Comment: I broadly agree, but would point out that the lack of variation from year to year would make it an easy task for that person. The person could be recompensed from advertising, or helped by the community. I'd also say that there are small events, I know of in my local area, which are easily missed by broad searches. We can dream can't we.

Comment: This would be a cool feature. Sportive listing websites exist, this would be a cool feature to add, the listing owner could tag the listing with any famous climb, then users search by the tag if they want. I'm doubtful of it coming to be, but sounds cool